# SSMS - develop an extension to modify selected strings to be with quotes and comma separated

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssms, visual-studio-extensions

While working in SSMS - it's a very frequent operation to copy some array of strings separated with a new line (\r\n) and then quote it and separate with a comma (just to use in IN SQL clause). Now I have to hold ALT key and do a vertical selection. I would like to develop an add-in to SSMS and assign it to hotkeys, but actually there is no info at all for the modern SSMS (starting with 17 version) how to do this. 
There is a lot docs how to develop extensions for VS, but no for SSMS.

I realize this not a SO question, but don't know where to ask - maybe there is some doc how to develop SSMS extensions starting from v17?

P.S. Maybe SSMS already have an extension to quote and separate with commas strings selected?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I made an extension and it works well with VS, have no idea how to "move" it into SSMS

Comment: You can use Visual Commander for SSMS to run your code in SSMS.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to create VSIX project using Visual Studio, compile it and copy to SSMS extension folder.
After that you need to configure SSMS to skip validation for 'unknown' VSIX extensions.

I recommend to check this approach:
https://github.com/benlaan/sqlformat

Tutorial from MS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2017

Code-project tutorial:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1243356/Create-Your-Own-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-SSMS